# Interferência de efeitos hover

Tags: html, css

Estou enfrentando um problema estranho. Tenho alguns links para as redes sociais com um `border-radius` e com efeito de `hover` de rotação da borda, como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando dou `hover` nesses links das redes sociais, uma `div` lá em outra parte do site perde seu `border-radius`.
Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não tenho ideia do que possa estar dando essa interferência, já que cada um teu sua classe. Alguém sabe?

[Visualização online](http://jsfiddle.net/rLrqzy4j/).
(Acredito que o problema esteja no plugin do slider - Cycle2)

CSS dos links das redes sociais:

```
.link-social { width:31px; height:31px; display:inline-block; }
.link-social:before {
display:block; content:""; width:31; height:31px; border:1px #DF9201 solid;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px; -moz-border-radius: 15px; border-radius: 15px;
}
.link-social:hover:before {
border:1px #DF9201 dashed; 
transform:rotate(36000deg); -webkit-transform:rotate(36000deg); -moz-transform:rotate(36000deg);
transition: all 500s ease; -webkit-transition: all 500s ease; -moz-transition: all 500s ease; -o-transition: all 500s ease;
}
```

CSS da div redonda:

```
.shape-slideshow { width:617px; height:617px; -webkit-border-radius:50%; -moz-border-radius:50%; border-radius:50%; overflow:hidden; }
```

Comment: Faltou o HTML :)

Comment: Beleza, coloquei lá.

Comment: [Efeito borboleta](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teoria_do_caos) :)

Comment: Parece um bug do Webkit. Vi ocorrer no Chrome e no Safari, mas não no Firefox.

Comment: Poisé. Vou tentar trocar de plugin de slider.. talvez funcione. Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Ah, eu não tinha reparado que o plugin estava no seu jsfiddle. Sem ele de fato não ocorre. E mesmo com ele, não ocorre se desligar a transição no hover do outro elemento. Mas não consegui descobrir a causa exata.

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente seja um div mal fechado no código, testando aqui no JSFiddle, percebi que se encontram 2 divs fechados no final, enquanto eu tirei um e fechei apos o código do facebook, e ficou normal.

```
Era pra ser assim?
```

> [image: Imagem do JSFiddle]

Fechei o segundo div, que esta depois do div do facebook nessa parte:

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-fx="fade" data-cycle-timeout="10000" data-cycle-pager=".slide-pager"></div>
```

Se esse for o caso, o erro ocorre pois uma div estava pareada com a outra causando o mesmo efeito sobre o outro, já que um tinha uma classe diferente, elas se juntam e formam um só efeito, na maioria dos casos.

Comment: Aqui todas as `divs` estão fechadas, estranho. Mesmo assim, obrigado. Eu acabei retirando esse efeito. :)